# Merge multiple JsonNodes into an array with Jackson

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I need to write some appender method that adds "JsonNode" objects together.
In the end, this would run recursively over a few hundreds of iterations.
Eventually I would convert it to an Avro object. So apart from "just getting it to work" I would also want to keep memory consumption into consideration.

A simplified example below:

```
  val s1 = """{"condition": "yes",
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File" }"""

  val s2 = """{"condition": "no",
    "id": "file2",
    "value": "File2" }"""

  val mapper = new ObjectMapper()

  val obj1: JsonNode = mapper.readTree(s1)
  val obj2: JsonNode = mapper.readTree(s2)

  // the following doesn't work obviously, but that's what I'm trying to do
  val result = obj1 + obj2
  println(result.toString)
```

the desired output would be:

```
[{"condition": "yes",
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File" },
 {"condition": "no",
    "id": "file2",
    "value": "File2" }]
```

I've been fiddling around with a few options, but I can't seem to get an easy append to work. Unless of course I go the "string" route, but that's not as clean as I would like it to be. (append s1 and s2 seperated by a `,` and wrap it in `[]` brackets)

Comment: I am not sure about memory consumption, but you could try ArrayNode.add, or just manipulate the strings manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @yokomizor already commented, you need to build an [`ArrayNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html) with the two elements `obj1` and `obj2`:

```
val result: ArrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode()
result.add(obj1)
result.add(obj2)
```

or even simpler:

```
val result: ArrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode().add(obj1).add(obj2)
```

The additional memory foot-print of this is as small as it can be,
because the [internal implementation of `ArrayNode`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.java#L27)
simply has a `private List<JsonNode> _children`,
and you have the `JsonNode`s already in memory anyway.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see this, I recall trying something similiar but all the while trying to parse the JsonNode as Arraynode (which doesn't work). Thanks for going the extra mile and figuring out the memory footprint!